# how to use a sql substring in a where in string list conditional

Tags: sql-server

I have a where conditional

```
where
pnumber in ('mem1234', 'mem2345','mem8978')
```

I need a substring without the mem in this where conditional.  There are a couple hundred strings in this where conditional.

What is the syntax for this?

Comment: I don't follow what you're asking here. If you don't want the `mem` just don't write it: `'1234'` instead of `'mem1234`, for example.

Comment: the list of members is an extract from a csv  I'd like to just paste the list in and not have to strip off the mem first if sql can do it   I tried this, but its alot of editing   in ((right'mem1234',4), right('mem2345',4),right('mem8978',4))

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Why not paste, highlight the `IN`, hit `Ctrl`+`H` and the replace mem with nothing in your selection?

Comment: You could simply add `mem` to the start of `pnumber`, i.e. `CONCAT('mem', pnumber) IN ('mem1234', 'mem2345','mem8978')`. This is going to mean that you can't use any index on `pnumber` though. You can't manipulate the `IN` list directly, but if you are simply copy and pasting out of csv, you could copy and paste as a table value constructor and manipulate that way, e.g. `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES ('mem1234'), ('mem2345'),('mem8978')) x (no) WHERE TRY_CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(x.No, 4, LEN(x.No))) = pnumber)`. At this level of effort though, you may as well just remove `mem` in the csv.

Comment: I would handle this already at import time. While reading the csv file, you could already perform something like `CAST(REPLACE(pnumber, 'mem','') AS INT)`... if the original text is required anyways, simply store the result in an additional numeric column (e.g. int or bigint depending on the possible values).

Comment: I am seeing that stripping off the MEM in the csv file is much easier.  Just thought I'd see if there an sql trick.

Answer (score 0):

In order to manipulate the data you will first need to insert it into a temp table/ table variable and then depending on how consistant your data is you could try the following:

```
DECLARE @pNumbers TABLE (item varchar(20))
insert into @pNumbers values('mem1234'),('mem2345'),('mem8978')
select 
    REPLACE(item, 'mem', '') AS ReplaceMethod ,
    SUBSTRING(item, 4, 4) AS SubstringMethod,
    RIGHT(item,LEN(item) - 3) AS Right_LenMethod
FROM @pNumbers
```

You would then add one of them methods to a subquery in the WHERE

```
WHERE 
pnumber IN ( SELECT REPLACE(item, 'mem', '') FROM @pNumbers )
```

Or as others have stated, you could open the csv in an external program and find and replace but atleast you have options